# Construction of Presheaf category such that subobjects of the terminal functor give a desired Heyting Algebra

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Given any Heyting algebra $H$, can you construct a category $\mathcal{C}$ such that the the subfunctors of the terminal presheaf on $\mathcal{C}$ (assign singleton to every object) form H?

That is
$$\textrm{Sub}_\mathcal{[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op},\;\mathbf{Set}]}(1)\cong H$$

where $1\colon\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$ is $1(C)=\{0\}$ for all $C\in\mathcal{C}$.

EDIT: H is a complete Heyting algebra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathsf{Sub}(1)$ is a *complete* Heyting algebra for any category $\mathcal C$, so there is no choice of $\mathcal C$ that will make $\mathsf{Sub}(1)$ isomorphic to a *non-complete* Heyting algebra.

Comment: And also, $\mathsf{Sub}_\mathcal{E}(1)$ is a [frame](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/frame) for any topos $\mathcal{E}$, so we can add that to the list of necessary conditions needed to ensure that the question is nontrivial.